# Is it possible to get the value type from an arbitrary iterator (C++)?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Value>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(const Iterator& it) { ... }
  ...
 private:
   map<Value, int> m_;
  }
};
```

Is there any way to get rid of Value in the template? The Iterator may or may not be an STL iterator, but it's guaranteed that *it type is Value.

I know about `iterator_traits<T>::value_type` for STL iterators, but wonder if there's any way to get Value type automatically for an arbitrary Iterator type?

One trick I'm thinking about - say, we have a helper class

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Value>
class Bar {
 public:
  Bar(const Iterator& dummy_iterator, const Value& dummmy_value) {}
  ...
};
```

Then if we instantiate Bar as Bar(it, *it), the type of Value will be known inside Bar. But I can't find a good way to combine Bar with Foo.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Any* iterator should provide `iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type`. If it does not, then it is not an iterator. ISO C++ 2003 24.3.1[lib.iterator.traits] "Iterator traits":

> To implement algorithms only in terms
>   of iterators, it is often necessary to
>   determine the value and difference
>   types that correspond to a particular
>   iterator type. Accordingly, it is
>   required that if `Iterator` is the type
>   of an iterator, the types
>
> ```
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category
> ```
>
> be defined as the iterator’s
>   difference type, value type and
>   iterator category, respectively.

Aside from that, there's no general way to obtain a type of an arbitrary C++ expression. C++0x will rectify it by providing `decltype`.

Comment: Thanks, the reference to ISO C++ standard is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. The correct way to get rid of `Value` is to use `iterator_traits` as you suggested.

If your non-STL iterator is a naked pointer, then you get correct iterator_traits typedefs for free. Otherwise the non-STL iterator class must define the correct typedefs.

See the [iterator traits documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/iterator_traits.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As to getting value type of iterator previous answers were correct.

But there is more. The trick you are thinking of would not work with class. If `Bar` was a function like:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Value>
void bar(const Iterator& dummy_iterator, const Value& dummmy_value) {}
```

then type deduction would work for `bar(it, *it)` and you would have the value type inside of `bar`. (But keep in mind that to use this trick you would still have to have a dereferencable iterator it which is not always good - how to deal with empty sequence then?)

Using a class `Bar` you would have to provide the template arguments `Iterator` and `Value` manually as there is no type deduction for classes and using `Bar(it, *it)` would no compile.

Comment: Thanks! I figured the same about using bar as function, but thought maybe I'm missing something.